# Retrive data fromphp array match to specific dates in a pricerange

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have mysql db with a lot of data base on bookingdates - with different prices attached to each date.

I have gotten the array out of the db - but how do I sort get the page to view only the selected dates prices - array below is for the first date - as you can see there is 4 types of prices - 7, 14, 21, 28 days.

My goal is to create an select option based on a foreach loop which has to return the specific price for the given date.

I know I have to use som jquery to optain that goal but I can't figure out how

I hope som of you experts can help with this - thanks in advance

```
object(stdClass)[11646]
      public 'lodging_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'lan' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'arrival' => string '2019-02-02' (length=10)
      public 'departure' => string '2019-02-09' (length=10)
      public 'unittype_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'duration' => string '7' (length=1)
      public 'currency' => string 'DKK' (length=3)
      public 'price' => string '3500' (length=4)
      public 'winterrulewarning' => string 'false' (length=5)
      public 'isavailable' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'priority' => string 'Normal' (length=6)
      public 'normalprice' => string '3500' (length=4)
      public 'hasdiscount' => string 'false' (length=5)
      public 'pets' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'infants' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'children' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'adults' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'languageid' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'isregularweek' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'boardtypeid' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'booking_status' => string 'Booking' (length=7)
      public 'dayswithdiscount' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'dayswithaddition' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'created' => string '2019-02-02 08:12:39' (length=19)
      public 'updated' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'disabled' => string '2019-02-02 17:28:01' (length=19)
      public 'session' => string '3556' (length=4)
      public 'status' => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[11647]
      public 'lodging_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'lan' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'arrival' => string '2019-02-02' (length=10)
      public 'departure' => string '2019-02-16' (length=10)
      public 'unittype_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'duration' => string '14' (length=2)
      public 'currency' => string 'DKK' (length=3)
      public 'price' => string '7000' (length=4)
      public 'winterrulewarning' => string 'false' (length=5)
      public 'isavailable' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'priority' => string 'Normal' (length=6)
      public 'normalprice' => string '7000' (length=4)
      public 'hasdiscount' => string 'false' (length=5)
      public 'pets' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'infants' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'children' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'adults' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'languageid' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'isregularweek' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'boardtypeid' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'booking_status' => string 'Booking' (length=7)
      public 'dayswithdiscount' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'dayswithaddition' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'created' => string '2019-02-02 08:12:39' (length=19)
      public 'updated' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'disabled' => string '2019-02-02 17:28:01' (length=19)
      public 'session' => string '3556' (length=4)
      public 'status' => string '0' (length=1)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[11648]
      public 'lodging_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'lan' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'arrival' => string '2019-02-02' (length=10)
      public 'departure' => string '2019-02-23' (length=10)
      public 'unittype_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'duration' => string '21' (length=2)
      public 'currency' => string 'DKK' (length=3)
      public 'price' => string '10500' (length=5)
      public 'winterrulewarning' => string 'false' (length=5)
      public 'isavailable' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'priority' => string 'Normal' (length=6)
      public 'normalprice' => string '10500' (length=5)
      public 'hasdiscount' => string 'false' (length=5)
      public 'pets' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'infants' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'children' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'adults' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'languageid' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'isregularweek' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'boardtypeid' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'booking_status' => string 'Booking' (length=7)
      public 'dayswithdiscount' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'dayswithaddition' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'created' => string '2019-02-02 08:12:40' (length=19)
      public 'updated' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'disabled' => string '2019-02-02 17:28:01' (length=19)
      public 'session' => string '3556' (length=4)
      public 'status' => string '0' (length=1)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[11649]
      public 'lodging_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'lan' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'arrival' => string '2019-02-02' (length=10)
      public 'departure' => string '2019-03-02' (length=10)
      public 'unittype_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'duration' => string '28' (length=2)
      public 'currency' => string 'DKK' (length=3)
      public 'price' => string '14000' (length=5)
      public 'winterrulewarning' => string 'false' (length=5)
      public 'isavailable' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'priority' => string 'Normal' (length=6)
      public 'normalprice' => string '14000' (length=5)
      public 'hasdiscount' => string 'false' (length=5)
      public 'pets' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'infants' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'children' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'adults' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'languageid' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'isregularweek' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'boardtypeid' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'booking_status' => string 'Booking' (length=7)
      public 'dayswithdiscount' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'dayswithaddition' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'created' => string '2019-02-02 08:12:40' (length=19)
      public 'updated' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'disabled' => string '2019-02-02 17:28:01' (length=19)
      public 'session' => string '3556' (length=4)
      public 'status' => string '0' (length=1)

 object(stdClass)[11646]
      public 'lodging_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'lan' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'arrival' => string '2019-02-02' (length=10)
      public 'departure' => string '2019-02-09' (length=10)
      public 'unittype_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'duration' => string '7' (length=1)
      public 'currency' => string 'DKK' (length=3)
      public 'price' => string '3500' (length=4)
      public 'winterrulewarning' => string 'false' (length=5)
      public 'isavailable' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'priority' => string 'Normal' (length=6)
      public 'normalprice' => string '3500' (length=4)
      public 'hasdiscount' => string 'false' (length=5)
      public 'pets' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'infants' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'children' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'adults' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'languageid' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'isregularweek' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'boardtypeid' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'booking_status' => string 'Booking' (length=7)
      public 'dayswithdiscount' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'dayswithaddition' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'created' => string '2019-02-02 08:12:39' (length=19)
      public 'updated' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'disabled' => string '2019-02-02 17:28:01' (length=19)
      public 'session' => string '3556' (length=4)
      public 'status' => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[11647]
      public 'lodging_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'lan' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'arrival' => string '2019-02-02' (length=10)
      public 'departure' => string '2019-02-16' (length=10)
      public 'unittype_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'duration' => string '14' (length=2)
      public 'currency' => string 'DKK' (length=3)
      public 'price' => string '7000' (length=4)
      public 'winterrulewarning' => string 'false' (length=5)
      public 'isavailable' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'priority' => string 'Normal' (length=6)
      public 'normalprice' => string '7000' (length=4)
      public 'hasdiscount' => string 'false' (length=5)
      public 'pets' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'infants' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'children' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'adults' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'languageid' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'isregularweek' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'boardtypeid' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'booking_status' => string 'Booking' (length=7)
      public 'dayswithdiscount' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'dayswithaddition' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'created' => string '2019-02-02 08:12:39' (length=19)
      public 'updated' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'disabled' => string '2019-02-02 17:28:01' (length=19)
      public 'session' => string '3556' (length=4)
      public 'status' => string '0' (length=1)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[11648]
      public 'lodging_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'lan' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'arrival' => string '2019-02-02' (length=10)
      public 'departure' => string '2019-02-23' (length=10)
      public 'unittype_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'duration' => string '21' (length=2)
      public 'currency' => string 'DKK' (length=3)
      public 'price' => string '10500' (length=5)
      public 'winterrulewarning' => string 'false' (length=5)
      public 'isavailable' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'priority' => string 'Normal' (length=6)
      public 'normalprice' => string '10500' (length=5)
      public 'hasdiscount' => string 'false' (length=5)
      public 'pets' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'infants' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'children' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'adults' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'languageid' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'isregularweek' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'boardtypeid' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'booking_status' => string 'Booking' (length=7)
      public 'dayswithdiscount' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'dayswithaddition' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'created' => string '2019-02-02 08:12:40' (length=19)
      public 'updated' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'disabled' => string '2019-02-02 17:28:01' (length=19)
      public 'session' => string '3556' (length=4)
      public 'status' => string '0' (length=1)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[11649]
      public 'lodging_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'lan' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'arrival' => string '2019-02-02' (length=10)
      public 'departure' => string '2019-03-02' (length=10)
      public 'unittype_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'duration' => string '28' (length=2)
      public 'currency' => string 'DKK' (length=3)
      public 'price' => string '14000' (length=5)
      public 'winterrulewarning' => string 'false' (length=5)
      public 'isavailable' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'priority' => string 'Normal' (length=6)
      public 'normalprice' => string '14000' (length=5)
      public 'hasdiscount' => string 'false' (length=5)
      public 'pets' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'infants' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'children' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'adults' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'languageid' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'isregularweek' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'boardtypeid' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'booking_status' => string 'Booking' (length=7)
      public 'dayswithdiscount' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'dayswithaddition' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'created' => string '2019-02-02 08:12:40' (length=19)
      public 'updated' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'disabled' => string '2019-02-02 17:28:01' (length=19)
      public 'session' => string '3556' (length=4)
      public 'status' => string '0' (length=1)
```

Comment: Don't send unwanted information to the client side. you can filter out data using PHP at the server side and return the data to the client side.. It'll affect the performance too...

Comment: Pls share your PHP code to get a clear idea.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you are trying to filter the result by the number of days between arival and departure. I yould advise doing this in the database query using a WHERE filter and MySQLs `datediff` function (example for one week trips):

```
SELECT [...] FROM [...] WHERE DATEDIFF(arival, departure) == 7;
```

If you want all entries, but ordered by trip length, you can use the same function in the ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT [...] FROM [...] ORDER BY DATEDIFF(arival, departure);
```

Comment: I have the duration time ex. 7, 14, 21, 28 days - but the problem is that every date has it's own price tag so if a customer chooses the date 02-02-2018 then it costs ex. 3500 when he chooses 03-08-2018 it costs 9500
I have to show on the page the price for the selected date.

Answer (score 0):

This SQL query will help you to filter out the data.

```
SELECT price,arrival,departure FROM table_name;
```